# Rails - how to setup create action to make multiple associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think this is a pretty simple question, but I have an app that has User, Product, and Review models.

When a user creates a new review for a product, I currently have this in my create action for Review:

```
@review = @product.reviews.new(params[:review])
```

This works fine, but the review is associated with the product only and I also want to associate it with the creating user. However, if I do something like this:

```
@review = @product.reviews.new(params[:review])
@review = current_user.reviews.new(params[:review])
```

Would it create two instances of the review that are separate records? How could I do multiple associations like this with only one @review variable?

Just to note, I am not using polymorphic associations because as I understand it, I don't need to allow @review to belong to EITHER a product or user, as I always want to associate it with both.

Thus, in my Review model I have:

```
t.integer  :product_id
t.integer  :user_id
```

and my models look this:

Product:

```
has_many :reviews
```

User:

```
has_many :reviews
```

Review:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :product
```

First, is this setup correct? Am I right in not using polymorphic associations? If so, how can I write my controller code to do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Rails Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

You probably want something like this:

```
@review = @product.reviews.new(params[:review])
current_user.reviews << @review
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I will read the associations guide but it looks like I am OK.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. There is a lot of good info on that page for future reference.